# hide inline-block on overflow

Tags: javascript, css

Are there css, jQuery, javascript tricks to hide inline-block elements if they begin to (on resize) or are overflowing their parent? For example, a selector to set display none on the overflowing element?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the css overflow property to

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Check [OverFlow](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) property of css

Check [OverFlow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) as described by Mozilla

If a containers overflow property is set to hidden then even if the content overflows it will stay hidden

Comment: This will clip the child content that overflows. Basically I'm looking for all or nothing. If any portion of the child content is hidden, don't show any of it.